# Can I customize Numberic key pad so that It should to covert the UITabbar

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I want to customize key pad so that ,it should not cover the tabbat at the bottom of window,
Please help

Comment: Dear ,I am stuck with many projects so i review this and I wll act on this ,so now please tell me the solution if you know ,and I think you are very expert I noticed from your answers....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ali if i am not wrong your keyboard is hiding your tabBar if this is a case then i suggest u to use the `annimation` and move your tabBar up with your keyboard......and the another option is you have to make a custom keyboad by customizing its parameters and open it where you want on your view for that google will help u!

Comment: custom key board may create may a reason for Apple to reject my app?